# How to handle multithreading MongoDb updates from .net classes?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

MongoDb, c# driver: Two threads are taking the same single document from MongoDb, changing its state and updating it back to database. I want every thread to detect if any changes were done by other thread between moments of reading and updating this document. If such changes are done by other thread, I do not want current thread to override them and I want to log this information. Please let me know possible solutions for that. I know there is `MongoCollection<T>.Update` and `MongoCollection<T>.FindAndModify` methods, where I can define query based on information taken from Db, but I do not see any ways to detect if the document was actually found and updated or not, there is no information like number of records updated returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, you want [optimistic locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).

A straightforward way to implement optimistic locking is to version your documents and increase the version number with every update, i.e.

```
public void Update(MyClass document)
{
    db.GetCollection<MyClass>("MyClass").Update(
        Query.And(
            Query<MyClass>.EQ(p => p.Id, document.Id), 
            Query<MyClass>(p => p.Version, document.Version),
            Update<MyClass>.Replace(document).Inc(p => p.Version));
}
```

Now let's suppose two threads A and B perform operations concurrently:

- A read document id 8, version = 5
- B read document id 8, version = 5
- B store update id 8, version = 6
- A attempt to store update on document id 8, version 5, but such an object no longer exists.

`MongoCollection<T>.Update` returns a `WriteConcernResult` which has a property `DocumentsAffected` that you can use to check whether a document was updated, or not.

Also see the MongoDB docs: [Isolate Sequence of Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/)

Comment: `DocumentsAffected` that's exactly what I need! Thanks